# What's happening to this plaster?

Tags: plaster, water-damage

[image]

As you can see:

1. Phones aren't meant to be cameras
2. The plaster in one of my room's corners is peeling off in one large chunk.

As far as I know, our house doesn't have a proper foundation and is sitting on limestone.

Mom says that the walls are sucking in groundwater, causing the plaster to loosen and that there is nothing we can do about it (keep in mind, we're in Hungary and have a limited budget). **Is that really the case?**

Comment: If "sitting on limestone" means either "right on the bedrock" or "on a wall built of limestone rocks" that's a proper foundation, unless the base of the wall is not adequately supported by the ground. You might still have the sort of problems generally solved by a "damp proof course" but there's nothing inherently improper about rock as a foundation.

Comment: Your mom is right, that does look like water damage

Comment: There's definitely signs of moisture, but that buckling looks like something moved.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I only know that when they were trying to get gas here, they couldn't drill through it. Also, what's a "damp proof course"?

Comment: @user125055 I believe this refers to waterproof "membrane" similar to "vapor barrier" but vapor barriers are applied to framed walls with insulation and waterproof membrane/"damp course" would be applied to concrete or rock foundation walls where moisture is present and problematic.